# Is there a way to ignore a single FindBugs warning?

Tags: java, warnings, findbugs, suppress-warnings

With PMD, if you want to ignore a specific warning, you can use `// NOPMD` to have that line be ignored.

Is there something similar for FindBugs?

Answer (score 346, accepted):

The FindBugs initial approach involves XML configuration files aka [filters](http://findbugs.sourceforge.net/manual/filter.html). This is really less convenient than the PMD solution but FindBugs works on bytecode, not on the source code, so comments are obviously not an option. Example:

```xml
<Match>
   <Class name="com.mycompany.Foo" />
   <Method name="bar" />
   <Bug pattern="DLS_DEAD_STORE_OF_CLASS_LITERAL" />
</Match>
```

However, to solve this issue, FindBugs later introduced another solution based on [annotations](http://findbugs.sourceforge.net/manual/annotations.html) (see [`SuppressFBWarnings`](http://findbugs.sourceforge.net/api/edu/umd/cs/findbugs/annotations/SuppressFBWarnings.html)) that you can use at the class or at the method level (more convenient than XML in my opinion). Example (maybe not the best one but, well, it's just an example):

```
@edu.umd.cs.findbugs.annotations.SuppressFBWarnings(
    value="HE_EQUALS_USE_HASHCODE", 
    justification="I know what I'm doing")
```

Note that since FindBugs 3.0.0 `SuppressWarnings` has been deprecated in favor of `@SuppressFBWarnings` because of the name clash with Java's `SuppressWarnings`.

Comment: Bonus Question: How do I find the appropriate value for a given reported "bug" (using sonar)?

Comment: The problem, of course with using the annotation approach is that your code rather needlessly imports (and subsequent dependency) the Findbugs library :(

Comment: @AshleyWalton the annotations' retention are CLASS, so at least it's only a compile time dependency

Comment: For those Maven users, you can use the following to import the annotations. (Bonus, the scope is set so your project doesn't depend on FindBugs at runtime).
`<dependency>
   <groupId>net.sourceforge.findbugs</groupId>
   <artifactId>annotations</artifactId>
   <version>1.3.2</version>
   <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>`

Comment: @PlanBForOpenOffice In Sonar, the FindBugs bug name is called "rule key", and can be found by clicking on the rule name.

Comment: "@edu.umd.cs.findbugs.annotations.SuppressWarnings" works, but how do I specify multiple values?

Comment: Maven users should add `<dependency><groupId>com.google.code.findbugs</groupId><artifactId>annotations</artifactId><version>3.0.0</version><scope>provided</scope></dependency>` to their POM if they want to use `@SuppressFBWarnings`.

Answer (score 39):

As others Mentioned, you can use the `@SuppressFBWarnings` Annotation.
If you don't want or can't add another Dependency to your code, you can add the Annotation to your Code yourself, Findbugs dosn't care in which Package the Annotation is.

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.CLASS)
public @interface SuppressFBWarnings {
    /**
     * The set of FindBugs warnings that are to be suppressed in
     * annotated element. The value can be a bug category, kind or pattern.
     *
     */
    String[] value() default {};

    /**
     * Optional documentation of the reason why the warning is suppressed
     */
    String justification() default "";
}
```

Source: https://sourceforge.net/p/findbugs/feature-requests/298/#5e88

Answer (score 18):

Here is a more complete example of an XML filter (the example above by itself will not work since it just shows a snippet and is missing the `<FindBugsFilter>` begin and end tags):

```
<FindBugsFilter>
    <Match>
        <Class name="com.mycompany.foo" />
        <Method name="bar" />
        <Bug pattern="NP_BOOLEAN_RETURN_NULL" />
    </Match>
</FindBugsFilter>
```

If you are using the Android Studio FindBugs plugin, browse to your XML filter file using File->Other Settings->Default Settings->Other Settings->FindBugs-IDEA->Filter->Exclude filter files->Add.

Answer (score 15):

**Update Gradle**

```
dependencies {
    compile group: 'findbugs', name: 'findbugs', version: '1.0.0'
}
```

**Locate the FindBugs Report**

> file:///Users/your_user/IdeaProjects/projectname/build/reports/findbugs/main.html

**Find the specific message**

[image: find bugs]

**Import the correct version of the annotation**

```
import edu.umd.cs.findbugs.annotations.SuppressWarnings;
```

**Add the annotation directly above the offending code**

```
@SuppressWarnings("OUT_OF_RANGE_ARRAY_INDEX")
```

See here for more info: [findbugs Spring Annotation](http://codedevstuff.blogspot.com/2016/08/suppress-findbugs-warnings-in-java-and.html)

Comment: You can use `compile 'net.sourceforge.findbugs:annotations:1.3.2'` syntax instead which is shorter.

Comment: +1, but kindly update your answer with: gradle `testCompile 'com.google.code.findbugs:annotations:3.0.0'` and annotation name `@SuppressFBWarnings`

Answer (score 11):

At the time of writing this (May 2018), FindBugs seems to have been replaced by [SpotBugs](https://spotbugs.github.io/SpotBugs). Using the `SuppressFBWarnings` annotation requires your code to be compiled with Java 8 or later and introduces a compile time dependency on `spotbugs-annotations.jar`.

Using a filter file to filter SpotBugs rules has no such issues. The documentation is [here](http://spotbugs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/filter.html).

Comment: Your link to SpotBugs seems to be incorrect. I found it at https://spotbugs.github.io/ instead.

Answer (score 10):

While other answers on here are valid, they're not a full recipe for solving this.

In the spirit of completeness:

You need to have the findbugs annotations in your pom file - they're only compile time, so you can use the `provided` scope:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.google.code.findbugs</groupId>
  <artifactId>findbugs-annotations</artifactId>
  <version>3.0.1</version>
  <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

This allows the use of `@SuppressFBWarnings` there is another dependency which provides `@SuppressWarnings`. However, the above is clearer.

Then you add the annotation above your method:

E.g.

```
@SuppressFBWarnings(value = "RCN_REDUNDANT_NULLCHECK_WOULD_HAVE_BEEN_A_NPE",
        justification = "Scanning generated code of try-with-resources")
@Override
public String get() {
    try (InputStream resourceStream =  owningType.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(resourcePath);
         BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(resourceStream, UTF_8))) { ... }
```

This includes both the name of the *bug* and also a reason why you're disabling the scan for it.

Finally you need to re-run findbugs to clear the error.

Answer (score -8):

I'm going to leave this one here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14509697/1356953

Please note that this works with `java.lang.SuppressWarnings`so no need to use a separate annotation.

> @SuppressWarnings on a field only suppresses findbugs warnings
>   reported for that field declaration, not every warning associated with
>   that field.
>
> For example, this suppresses the "Field only ever set to null"
>   warning:
>
> @SuppressWarnings("UWF_NULL_FIELD") String s = null; I think the best
>   you can do is isolate the code with the warning into the smallest
>   method you can, then suppress the warning on the whole method.

Comment: `java.lang.SuppressWarnings` can't work. It has source retention, so is not visible to findbugs.