# GWT and FindBugs: How to solve "Internationalization - Consider using Locale parameterized version of invoked method" error?

Tags: gwt, locale, findbugs

I'm trying to achieve harmony between FindBugs and GWT 2.4 (being used with Java 6).  FindBugs complains about this line ...

```
childrenStr.append(child.getName().toLowerCase());
```

with the error

```
Internationalization - Consider using Locale parameterized version of invoked method
```

To attempt to heal the pain, I added a Locale ...

```
childrenStr.append(child.getName().toLowerCase(Locale.ENGLISH));
```

but then GWT dies with the compile error ...

```
[ERROR] Line 346: The method toLowerCase() in the type String is not applicable for the arguments (Locale)
```

How can I achieve a lasting peace between the two whereby I resolve the FindBugs error and keep GWT quiet?

Thanks, - Dave

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since GWT [doesn't include support](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/RefJreEmulation.html) for the locale sensitive [`String#toLowerCase(Locale)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#toLowerCase(java.util.Locale)) method and there is no locale sensitive lowercase conversion in the GWT API, [suppress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1829904/is-there-a-way-to-ignore-a-single-findbugs-warning) the FindBugs [`DM_CONVERT_CASE`](http://findbugs.sourceforge.net/bugDescriptions.html#DM_CONVERT_CASE) warning:

```
@edu.umd.cs.findbugs.annotations.SuppressWarnings(
    value="DM_CONVERT_CASE", 
    justification="No GWT emulation of String#toLowerCase(Locale)")
public void lowercaseUser() {
  childrenStr.append(child.getName().toLowerCase());
}
```