# Findbugs: RV_RETURN_VALUE_IGNORED_BAD_PRACTICE

Tags: java, io, findbugs

I am using `FindBugs` to analyze my code in Eclipse from Ant.

Following snippet gives `RV_RETURN_VALUE_IGNORED_BAD_PRACTICE`:

> RV: Method ignores exceptional return value
>   (RV_RETURN_VALUE_IGNORED_BAD_PRACTICE)
>
> This method returns a value that is not checked. The return value
>   should be checked since it can indicate an unusual or unexpected
>   function execution. For example, the File.delete() method returns
>   false if the file could not be successfully deleted (rather than
>   throwing an Exception). If you don't check the result, you won't
>   notice if the method invocation signals unexpected behavior by
>   returning an atypical return value.

```
public void export (File file) throws IOException {
    if (!file.exists()) {
        file.createNewFile();
    }

    BufferedWriter bw = null;
    try {
        bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file.getAbsoluteFile()));
    ...
```

Actually I don't care where file existed or not, the method should keep executing. If exception happened it would be thrown outside of `export()`

**How can I rewrite this snippet, so warning/error is not shown, without disabling it in Findbugs config file?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In that particular case, you don't have to call `file.createNewFile()` because the file will be created anyway by `FileWriter`.

However, you must assure that the parent folder for the file exists.

Comment: Yes, just remove the `if` altogether. But I wonder why anyone wouldn't care if his program works in the first place.

Answer (score 4):

`f.createNewFile();` returns `boolean` value

> **true** if the named file does not exist and was successfully created;
>   **false** if the named file already exists

change method to `boolean result = f.createNewFile();`

You should probably change the code if you do not care whether the file exists or not to **exclude the check** for `exists` and directly creating `BufferedWriter` which will create the file if it does not exist. Also if you still want to go with the present code add `SuppressWarnings` to ignore the warning.

Comment: "returns boolean value" I know, but it would not eliminate the message if `result` is not handled differently.

Comment: if you dont care then you can ignore them using `SuppressWarnings`. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1829904/is-there-a-way-to-ignore-a-single-findbugs-warning I will also edit my post for that,