# Why is findbugs throwing a null pointer dereference in this code?

Tags: java, findbugs

I'm running findbugs on our code through Sonarqube, and I'm getting an error for a null pointer dereference:

> There is a branch of statement that, if executed, guarantees that a
>   null value will be dereferenced.

The faulty code is simply this:

```
public static boolean isBigDecimalDifferent(BigDecimal x, BigDecimal y) {
        return (x != null || y != null)
                && ((x != null && y == null) || (x == null && y != null) || x.compareTo(y) != 0);   
}
```

I'm wondering how this is possible. The only place where an NPE is possible is when calling x.compareTo(y), but if x=null then Java will never analyse that branch, right?

Is this a bug, or am I missing something about the way Java would analyse this statement?

---

**UPDATE**

Thanks for the input. I ended up suggesting them to change it to something like:

```
if (x!=null && y != null)
    return x.compare(y);
else
    return x!=y;
```

which I find a bit clearer. If no one agrees to the change, I'll do as suggested and just ignore the issue, even though I'd rather avoid that.

Comment: Simply?  Nothing simple about this code.  It's very hard to read and understand.  I'd refactor it.

Comment: unless x is null and y is not null

Comment: What do you want to test? I think FindBugs is getting confused because of all the boolean checks, I can't find a path that would lead to a NPE. Try to refactor the code.

Comment: The code is horrible but is logically null-safe. Horrible though.

Comment: Yeah, I agree completely, I had to make a boolean table just to make sure of what it was trying to do. Unfortunately, it is legacy code that I haven't authority to change (I do wish I could!)

Comment: @Stultuske In that case, I believe it would never reach the last branch, since (x == null && y != null) would return true before that happened.

Comment: I too agree the logic is too complex for FindBugs. I would go for something like https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.1/org/apache/commons/lang3/ObjectUtils.html

Comment: @lv my bad. the problem is when both are null, it seems. the code is indeed a mess to read.

Comment: if you write ugly code you might as well want to keep it as short as possible :P : `return x == null || y == null ? x != y : x.compareTo(y) != 0;` will do the same ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The logic is just too complex for FindBugs, it's getting it wrong here. You're right that you've defended against dereferencing `null` in that code.

I'd simplify it, so FindBugs understands it, and so that any subsequent human reader can also easily make out what it's doing:

```
public static boolean isBigDecimalDifferent(BigDecimal x, BigDecimal y) {
    if (x == null) {
        return y != null;
    }
    if (y == null) {
        return x != null;
    }
    return x.compareTo(y) != 0;
}
```

---

Side note: Usually, you'd have a method to check for *equality*, and use `!` if you want to check for inequality.

---

In a comment you've said:

> Unfortunately, it is legacy code that I haven't authority to change (I do wish I could!)

Then you'll have to note that FindBugs can't figure it out, and make it an exception in your FindBugs setup ([described in this question's answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1829904/is-there-a-way-to-ignore-a-single-findbugs-warning)).

Answer (score 0):

I'd write that method this way:

```
public static boolean isBigDecimalDifferent(BigDecimal x, BigDecimal y) {
   if (x == null) throw new IllegalArgumentException("x cannot be null");
   if (y == null) throw new IllegalArgumentException("y cannot be null");
   return (x.compareTo(y) != 0);
}
```

I think it's far easier to read.

If you don't want the pre-conditions expressed in exceptions I'd say this is clearer, too:

```
public static boolean isBigDecimalDifferent(BigDecimal x, BigDecimal y) {
   if (x == null) return (y != null);
   if (y == null) return (x != null);
   return (x.compareTo(y) != 0);
}
```

Comment: @DavideLorenzoMARINO: throwin an unexpected exception, or one that is foreseen...