# Why does findbugs give redundant nullcheck for one method but not the other

Tags: java, findbugs

I've been using the @Nonnull and @Nullable annotations on methods to give other programmers (and myself!) a clue about what a method can return. I finally decided to actually run Findbugs on a class (IntelliJ - FindBugs-IDEA v1.0.1), and I don't understand the behavior I'm seeing. The documentation hasn't helped either.

Let's say I have the following example code:

```
import javax.annotation.Nonnull;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    }

    @Nonnull
    public static String myFunc(){
        return new String("foo");
    }

    @Nonnull
    public static String myFunc2(){
        return "foo";
    }
}
```

Findbugs flags myFunc()'s return statement as having "Redundant nullcheck of value known to be non-null", but is happy with myFunc2().

Is it expected that findbugs sees these differently? (Link to documentation would be appreciated) Am I completely misunderstanding the use of @Nonnull on methods?

[edit]

After some research, I've decided that the org.jetbrains [@Contract](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.3/contract-annotations.html) annotation (with contract violations changed to errors) will better serve my needs. Thank you Guillaume F. for your help!

Comment: Neither can be null, but it's basically never necessary to use `new String("string literal")`.

Comment: Obviously. It just makes a much simpler example than my actual code.

Comment: But it sounds like you're omitting pertinent details: are they `String`s, allowing you to use string literals; or are they something else?

Comment: I've added the complete class used to demonstrate the problem. It's not the use of the functions that findbugs is complaining about -- the error shows up on the 'return' line of myFunc. Remember, this is just an example.

Comment: Just another Findbugs bug.

Answer (score 3):

You have to understand what redundant Null-Check means. When Findbugs gives you this warning, it means you did a Null-Check two times, and the second time is not necessary. Which matches your example.

In the first code, `new String("foo")` does an implicit null check, because `new String(null)` will throw an Exception. So this new String object is checked non-null implicitly. Then you do another `@Nonnull` check while leaving the method. Findbugs sees this and gives you the warning.

In your second code, there is no such control since you return a raw String and do the `@Nonnull` check only once. Everything is fine.

---

Maybe you will want to use `edu.umd.cs.findbugs.annotations.NonNull` instead. This one will just hint Findbugs that you want a non-null result, without having a real check.

If you are using Maven:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.code.findbugs</groupId>
        <artifactId>annotations</artifactId>
        <version>${findbugs-annotations.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
```

---

https://blogs.oracle.com/java-platform-group/entry/java_8_s_new_type

[Which @NotNull Java annotation should I use?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4963300/which-notnull-java-annotation-should-i-use)

Comment: Thanks -- your explanation makes sense. Unfortunately, using edu.umd.cs.findbugs.annotations.NonNull doesn't change the result -- not only does it still complain about the redundant check, it also shows as deprecated, and recommends using javax.annotation.Nonnull. I think my best bet will be to search for an alternative to Findbugs, since this behavior is not what I want.

Comment: You can disable this specific warning in Findbugs options if it bothers you, or you can use `@SuppressWarnings` : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1829904/is-there-a-way-to-ignore-a-single-findbugs-warning I seen your edit, glad that you found a solution. If my answer helped, can you mark it as such? Thank you.